# Do closed line integrals need to be evaluated in "the line's" rest frame?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, reference-frames, integration, mathematics

I've seen it said that the definition of emf requires that the integral be carried out in the circuit's rest frame.
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{E} =\oint \mathbf{f} \cdotp d\mathbf{l}
\end{equation*}
Is this because emf is defined as a closed line integral, or is it because of another reason (if so, what)?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny that Q&A refers to the special case of a single open circuit wire. Here the question is on a closed circuit.

Comment: @GiorgioP oh oh, wrong question!

Comment: What is $\bf f$ in your definition of the emf?

Comment: @GiorgioP It is the force per unit charge on dl.

Comment: Which force? That is the key point.

Comment: @GiorgioP It is the force exerted by the electromagnetic field which the loop is in, as well as the force exerted by any other energy sources that interact electrically with q (for example, a battery).

Comment: I agree. But I asked this question to tune a possible answer. Unfortunately, sometimes there is some confusion even in the textbooks on the exact definition of emf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of reference frame when discussing Faraday's law may be pedagogically useful, but in my opinion, only after the physical content of the law has been grasped in the laboratory reference frame. Of course, the law can be expressed unambiguously in any reference frame, including that of the laboratory.

The really interesting part of Faraday's law is the presence of a non-conservative electric field in the presence of a local time variation of the magnetic field. This would imply to write  it in integral form as
$$
\oint_{C} \vec E \cdot {\rm d}\vec l = -\iint_{\Sigma} \frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}\cdot {\rm d}\vec S, \tag{1}
$$
where $\Sigma$ is an open surface having $C$ as a border (I am using SI units).
However, if the closed line $C$ is moving, in general, there is an additional force on a unit charge moving on the line due to the presence of the magnetic field (recall that we are working in the lab frame). If we define the emf as the integral of the force per unit charge on a line $C$, in the lab frame, we have
$$
emf = \oint_{C} \left( \vec E + \vec v \times \vec B\right)\cdot {\rm d}\vec l.
$$
Therefore, we have to sum the same term containing the line integral of $\vec v \times \vec B$ on the right-hand side of the equation ($1$). Luckily, a simple exercise of derivatives shows that this term can be rewritten as the minus the time derivative of the flux of $\vec B$ on the varying surface $\Sigma(t)$ *at fixed  $\vec B$. Combining the two terms, we end up with the usual form of Faraday's law.
$$
emf = \oint_{C} \left( \vec E + \vec v \times \vec B\right)\cdot {\rm d}\vec l = -\frac{{\rm d} }{{\rm d} t} \iint_{\Sigma}  \vec B\cdot {\rm d}\vec S.
$$

If, in addition to the $emf$ due to the total magnetic flux variation, other forces on the charges exist (for instance, the presence of batteries), they should be added to this *induced* $emf$.

So, we see that the definition of the $emf$ does not require the circuit rest frame. It is only when one wants to pick-up part of the emf, which does depend only on the time variation of the magnetic field, that it is useful to use the circuit's rest frame. Coming back to my starting remark, if one wants to show that the electromagnetic force can be reduced to a non-conservative electric field by using the instantaneous rest frame and the non-relativistic transformation of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

The following is based on information from the textbook Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics, using esu units.

Faraday's law of induction for the $emf$ is $emf = \oint_{C} \vec E' \cdot d\vec l$; this is evaluated in the reference frame where the circuit is at rest; therefore,  $\vec E'$ is the electric field at $d\vec l$ in the coordinate system in which $d \vec l$ is at rest, *because it is this field that causes current to flow in the circuit.*

For the electric field $\vec E$ in the laboratory (inertial frame): $\vec E' = \vec E + {1\over c}(\vec v \times\vec B)$ where $c$ is the speed of light, $\vec v$ is the velocity of the moving circuit in the laboratory frame, and $\vec B$ is the magnetic field in the laboratory frame at the circuit.

Comment: I did not check what exactly Jackson writes. However, as is, the statement looks only partially correct. What about a circuit where different parts move differently?

Comment: @GiorgioP Good question, thanks!  Jackson does not address this case.  I suppose you would evaluate each moving part in its reference frame, then convert each to the laboratory frame to do the overall evaluation.  Other Ideas?